# How to create 32-bit installation setup for 64-bit

Tags: windows, nsis

I have created a few setups using NSIS 2.46(Editor HM NIS 2.0.3). My setup involves a few registry settings to be created under `WriteRegStr HKCR "${PRODUCT_ROOT_CLSID}`.

How do i handle my 32-bit setups to install and work properly on 64-bit systems?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetRegView` if you don't want to be redirected to the 32bit part of the registry...

Answer (score 0):

```
GetVersion::WindowsPlatformArchitecture
Pop $R1
${If} $R1 == "32"
   MessageBox MB_OK "32 bits"
${ElseIf} $R1 == "64"
   MessageBox MB_OK "64 bits"
${Endif}
```